# uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SubResultComponent setDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000046b640'

Tags: swift, core-data, appdelegate, nsexception

I have an error to which I am not sure on how to fix.

Here is there error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SubResultComponent setDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000046b640'
```

Here is the SubResultComponent

```
extension SubResultComponent {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SubResultComponent> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SubResultComponent>(entityName: "SubResultComponent")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: String?
    @NSManaged public var price: NSDecimalNumber?

}
```

This is where I Call set date

```
func updateUI() {

    guard rateLog != nil else {

        return
    }

    // Update cell UI
    self.dateLabel.text = rateLog?.date
    self.priceLabel.text = numberFormatter.string(from: (rateLog?.price)!)
}
```

Comment: Could we see the code where you call setDate? Do you generate your core data code manually, maybe something is out of synch?

Comment: I have just added where I called setDate

Comment: No, there's no call to `setDate` there. In any case it would be nice to see more information: the crash log, more context showing what SubResultComponent is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`@NSManaged` acts similar to the objective c version of `dynamic`; it is a promise to the compiler that the object will have those properties at runtime. It does not actually make those properties.  For this to work these properties need to be setup correctly in the core data model file. Using the editor's "Create NSManagedObject Subclass..." option greatly helps in keeping you code and the model in sync.